# write to child process twice after nonblocking read

Tags: python, popen, nonblocking, child-process, read-write

I have a python loop that reads from multiple child processes (without blocking). Sometimes I have to write to that child process. **The first write goes through** but if I perform a *non-blocking* read then write to the child process again, **the second write never seems to go through** to the child process.

I believe if I perform a regular blocking read (process.stderr.readline()), the second read will go through. Any help?

### Python loop

```
# create mock process
childprocesses = []
p = subprocess.Popen(['./cprogram'], 
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
childprocesses.append(p)
loop_4eva()

# the loop
def loop_4eva():
    for process in childprocesses:
        if(process.poll() is None):
            process.stdin.write("first write\n")
            output = non_block_read(process.stderr).strip()
            print output
            process.stdin.write("second write\n")
            output = non_block_read(process.stderr).strip()
            print output


def non_block_read(output):
    fd = output.fileno()
    fl = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    try:
            return output.readline()
    except:
            return ''
```

### A child process (c program)

```
void main(){
    char buffer[256];
    while(1){
        fgets(buffer, 256, stdin);//read/buffer one line from stdin
        fprintf(stderr, "read: %s", buffer);//buffer includes '\n'
    }
}
```

### Output (python prints...)

> read: first write
>   //nothing else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`stdin` is line buffered in C. You will probably need to disable buffering in the child process to make this work. You'll also want to add a `process.stdin.flush()` to ensure you aren't getting buffered on the writer side.

Comment: Thanks but for some reason **setvbuf(stdin, NULL, _IOFBF, 1024);** in my C program fixed the problem. You pointed me in the right direction though!

Comment: For what it is worth, that switches `stdin` from line buffering to block buffering. You could have also used `setvbuf(stdin, 0, _IONBF, 0);` and that most likely would have also solved your problem, which is what I was saying by "disable buffering in the child process".